# p:column sortBy value expresson not evaluating to column index

Tags: primefaces

I'm having problems with sortBy in fixed columns of a lazy data table with mixed fixed and dynamic columns. Here is the table:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{formController.lazyModel}" var="record" rowKey="#{record.get(0)}" widgetVar="tableWidget"
         lazy="true" selection="#{formController.selectedRecord}" selectionMode="single" style="#{formController.tableStyle} min-width: 120px;"
         scrollable="true" scrollHeight="600" scrollWidth="100%" emptyMessage="#{sessionController.itemFormLabels['table_no_entries_msg']}" editable="true"
         paginator="true" rows="50" rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" paginatorPosition="bottom" filterDelay="500"
         paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{formController.onRowEdit}" update=":alowAddNewRecord :formTableForm:buttonPanel" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" onsuccess="cancelEditing();" />
<p:ajax event="page" onstart="blockTableInput();" oncomplete="enbleTableInput();" />

<f:facet name="header">

    <p:commandButton id="insertButton" value="#{sessionController.itemFormLabels['add_record_button']}" icon="fa fa-plus"
                     actionListener="#{formController.insertRecord}" disabled="#{not formController.alowAddNewRecord}"
                     title="#{sessionController.itemFormLabels['add_record_tip']}" onclick="saveLastRow();PF('tableWidget').clearFilters();"
                     update=":alowAddNewRecord :formTableForm:table :formTableForm:buttonPanel :growlMessages" />

</f:facet>

<p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{record[0]}" filterBy="#{record[0]}" filterMatchMode="contains" exportable="false"
          style="width: 50px; font-size: 12px !important;" rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(0).visible}">

           ...

</p:column>

<p:columns var="column" value="#{formController.columnsInfo}" columnIndexVar="colIndex" exportable="false"
           sortBy="#{record[column.columnIndex]}" filterBy="#{record[column.columnIndex]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
           rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(column.columnIndex).visible}"
           filterStyle="width: 90%" style="#{formController.columnsCustomStyles.get(column.columnIndex - 1)} font-size: 12px !important;">

           ...

</p:columns>

<p:column headerText="report header" sortBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + 1]}" exportable="false"
          filterBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + 1]}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width: 50px; font-size: 12px !important;"
          rendered="#{formController.tableInfo.tableType eq 1 and formController.formColumnList.get(formController.noColumns + 1).visible}">

          ...

</p:column>

<p:column headerText="user created" sortBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 1]}" exportable="false"
          filterBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 1]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
          style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px !important;" rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 1).visible}">

          ...

</p:column>

<p:column headerText="date created" sortBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 2]}" exportable="false"
          filterBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 2]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
          style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px !important;" rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 2).visible}">

          ...

</p:column>

<p:column headerText="user modified" sortBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 3]}" exportable="false"
          filterBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 3]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
          style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px !important;" rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 3).visible}">

          ...

</p:column>

<p:column headerText="date modified" sortBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 4]}" exportable="false"
          filterBy="#{record[formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 4]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
          style="width: 100px; font-size: 12px !important;" rendered="#{formController.formColumnList.get(formController.noColumns + formController.factColDelta + 4).visible}">

          ...

</p:column>

<p:column style="width:32px" exportable="false">
    <p:rowEditor />
</p:column>
```

If I invoke sort on the dynamic cloumns everything is fine. The sortBy value expression: `#{record[column.columnIndex]}` evaluates to a column index and the sort is working.
Whereas if I invoke sort on an fixed column, let's say the first one, the value expression `#{record[0]}` does not evaluate to the columns index 0, but to a string 'record[0]'.
This can be seen in the NumberFromatException that gets thrown when sorting is invoked:

> 12:09:52,336 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-1) Error Rendering View[/public/item_form.xhtml]: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "record[0]"
>       at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

I'm using Primefaces 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out where I have gone wrong. I have implemented a lazy table, and when doing so, one is responsible to write its own lazy model class which extents the `LazyDataModel` class which is also responsible for sorting and filtering. And I have done exactly what is required, however I have forgot to implement the handling of my non-dynamic columns.

So there are two sloutions:

1. enhance my lazy class with the information about my static columns (position in the list, data type etc.) and and add specific implementation for sorting and filtering of those columns.
2. add my static columns to the list which is rendered in the `p:columns` tag (i.e. ditch the non-dynamic columns), and add column styles and other info of the static columns to the corresponding lists describing the dynamic columns. This way one does not have to add implementation specific code to he lazy data model.

The second solution is neater and cleaner. Hope that this will enlighten others that make the same mistake I have made.